# Is there a way to determine where artifacts were published to in gradle's publish task?

Tags: maven, gradle

As the title says, is there a way to determine where artifacts were published in gradle's publish task? The reason being is that I'd like to have that information so I can send out an email with the URL's for downloading. Publishing isn't a problem - I've got that working through the `maven-publish`. But there doesn't seem to be a way to get that information that prints out on the screen while still inside of the build.

Edit:

For example, while publishing I get a readout of

`Upload http://xxxxxxxxxx:9000/archiva/repository/snapshots/com/xxxxxxxxxx/mobile/xxxxxxxxxx/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/xxxxxxxxxx-debug-unaligned-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.apk`

The program is obviously aware of exactly where the artifact was sent. Is there a way to pull that information out and use it in another task?

Comment: even with --debug or --info?

Comment: The URL's print to the screen in normal mode, but I would like to programmatically get those URL's while *still inside* the build process. In other words, I don't want to run the build, grep the result, and then run another program.

Comment: my understanding is when publishing, you should tell gradle the URL of maven repo (as well as credentials) so it can push..unless you are publishing locally. You may need to look at the "Convention Object" of the maven-publish task to see the configurations of this task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could get this information from the task itself. The `maven-publish` plugin creates a publish task per artifact per repository.

```
project.tasks.withType(PublishToMavenRepository).all { task ->
    task.doLast {
        def baseUrl = "${task.repository.url}/${task.publication.groupId.replace('.', '/')}/${task.publication.artifactId}/${task.publication.version}/${task.publication.artifactId}"
        task.publication.artifacts.each { artifact ->
            println "${baseUrl}${artifact.classifier ? '-' + artifact.classifier : ''}.${artifact.extension}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the URL of the repository, not of where the artifact was uploaded.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to give you the thumbs up on this, as I actually used what you posted earlier and got to basically the same conclusion.

Comment: anyone got the equivalent for kts there seems to be no .each in kts?